# issues with slide show in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this issues where the images can't display or javascript code is not working

The console show this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: settimeout is not defined
at changeimage (carousel2.html:22)
```

The output is hello

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 4000;
images[0] = 'images/cake.jpg';
images[1] = 'images/cake1.jpg';
images[2] = 'images/cake2.jpg';
images[3] = 'images/cake3.jpg';
images[4] = 'images/cake4.jpg';

function changeimage() {
  document.src = images[1];
  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  settimeout("changeimage()", time);
}
window.onload = changeimage;
```

```html
<title>carouse slide button</title>
<P>hello</P>
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout` (upper case)

Comment: document.src ??? You need to change an image somewhere

Comment: Also use this format: `setTimeout(changeimage, time);` or just use setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Issues in your code

1. Misspelled setTimeout
2. missing image tag
3. using images[1] over and over

You want to study this

```js
const time = 4000;
const images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/231/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/232/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/233/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/234/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/235/200/300"
];
let cnt = 0;
const changeImage = function() {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = images[cnt];
  cnt++;
  if (cnt >= images.length) cnt = 0;
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the page loads
  setInterval(changeImage, time); // call every 4 seconds
  changeImage(); // but call it now too so we do not have to wait
});
```

```html
<img id="img1" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The function `settimeout` is not correctly written. Should be:

```
setTimeout(changeimage, time);
```

For more info, you can check this [link](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval).

Comment: setTimeout(changeimage, time);

Comment: No! `setTimeout(changeimage, time); ` and it is a typo type question anyway